# make: No targets. Stop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

make is working strangely on my Makefile. It gives error "No targets. Stop". When I write make clean, it writes: "No rule to make target clean."
If i compile each file separately everything is fine. 
Below is the code:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall 
BOOSTIP = -I path/to/boost
default: abc
all: abc
abc: main.o node.o network.o   my_funs.o my_random.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BOOSTIP) main.o node.o network.o my_funs.o my_random.o -o abc  
main.o: main.cpp node.hpp network.hpp 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BOOSTIP) main.cpp -o main.o
node.o: node.cpp node.hpp my_funs.hpp my_random.hpp 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BOOSTIP) node.cpp -o node.o
network.o: network.cpp network.hpp node.hpp my_funs.hpp my_random.hpp 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BOOSTIP) network.cpp -o network.o
my_funs.o: my_funs.cpp my_funs.hpp node.hpp my_random.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BOOSTIP) my_funs.cpp -o my_funs.o
my_random.o: my_random.cpp my_random.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BOOSTIP)  my_random.cpp -o my_random.o
clean:
    rm abc *.o *~
```

Comment: I don't get that error when running your makefile. I had to change the spaces at the beginning of each line to tabs (which I suspect you have as well and they just didn't copy right in here). I get "No rule to make target main.cpp" which should be fine if I put main.cpp in my directory. you do not need "default: abc" as make will by default run the first target so all and default are the same thing.

Comment: What version of Make do you use? Have you tried a very simple makefile?

Comment: @Flexo I respectfully disagree with deleting my post.  In fact, my answer was exactly correct.  This question is precisely answered by following the route I gave. If it were "just look it up", it would be unappropriate.  But, I gave precise instructions to find the exact answer.  Repeating the section from that link is pointless.  For example, the contents there could change.  But to point the read er to it, is exactly right.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: I agree with Flexo, and I find your comment baffling. You think that quoting the manual is pointless because the manual might be revised later, but that directions to the manual *that rely on current Google ranks* are better?? And anyway, that part of the manual doesn't really explain how to fix the problem; I already knew what the error message meant, and yet I don't know why Piotr Górski is getting it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I managed to correct the error. It was a problem of Windows/Unix line ending... I had only CR, as it should be LF. 
@Beta: I managed to write the simple makefile and it worked correctly and that's why I thought about possible differences and checked the invisible signs. Thanks for idea!

Comment: @PiotrGórski please add an answer

Comment: @Beta well, you have a point about the current ranks, I should have said "there is a section in the manual, so-and-so".  My point is, the manual precisely states what the cause of that error message was supposed to be.  If Piotr had said "I checked the manual, says this is the cause, but no, I double-checked, it is not the case" - then, we are talking.  As it was when I answered it, it was a case of "did not look in the manual".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was due to bad line ending. Makefile had only CR, as it should have LF.
Correcting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error several times and in many of these cases the error was very simple, some space left after the value attributed to a variable, for an instance in make book where book: was the label of a sequence to LaTeX my book "name" in the attribution field have written  "text=name       ". Solution: "text=name" no spaces left behind name. Now I do define variables putting the sign of comment just at the end
to prevent this error: "text=name##"